# When performing text to columns for multiple columns spaces seem to affect the delimiting process

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My first worksheet contains a number of filled columns. At the bottom I have code that copies one of these columns into the second sheet and performs text to columns. It then repeats the process copying another column into the next available column in the second sheet.

**PROBLEM:**
It seems that when the code encounters a blank in the first cell of a particular column in the second sheet, the text to columns action doesn't work correctly.

If  columns in sheet 1 ("Paste in") looked like:

```
------------------------------------------
Column 1    column 2   column 3  column 4
a b         c  d                  e  f           
g h         i  j       k l        m n
```

---

After text to columns in sheet 2 ("TOP LINE") it wrongly looks something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  
a    b   c   d   e   f
g    h   i   j   k   n
```

---

Thus after cell 1 in column 3 in sheet 1 is found to be empty, some of the text in sheet 2 after column 4 is missing (l and m have disappeared). I think this is down to the following line from the code below but I'm not sure to be honest.

```
   Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, b), DataType:=xlDelimited,
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm tearing my hair out with this one!

```
Sub TextToColumns()

Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Range, column As Range


Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.ClearContents

For a = 1 To 60

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Excel.Sheets("Paste In").Columns(a)) > 0 Then
Excel.Sheets("Paste In").Columns(a).Copy
b = Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).column
Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Select


  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Columns(b)) > 0      Then b = b + 1
    Excel.Sheets("TOP LINE").Columns(b).EntireColumn.Select
    Excel.ActiveSheet.Paste
   Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, b), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1),   Array(6, 1), _
            Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
 End If
Next a

ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Rows.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to change the way you determine the value of `b` (the destination column for pasting). Something like `Do While {count in col(b) > 0}:b=b+1:Loop`

Comment: Can you use fixed-width columns instead of delimiters?

Comment: @ A. Webb - no it requires delimiters but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub TextToColumns()

    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer        
    Dim shtTop As Worksheet, shtPaste As Worksheet
    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set shtTop = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TOP LINE")
    Set shtPaste = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Paste In")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    shtTop.Cells.ClearContents

    For a = 1 To 60

        If wsf.CountA(shtPaste.Columns(a)) > 0 Then

            b = shtTop.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column
            Do While wsf.CountA(shtTop.Columns(b)) > 0
                b = b + 1
            Loop

            shtPaste.Columns(a).Copy shtTop.Cells(1, b)
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            shtTop.Columns(b).TextToColumns Destination:=shtTop.Columns(b), _
                DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), _
                Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), _
                TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        End If
    Next a

    With shtTop
        .Activate
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .Rows.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @ Tim Williams - Fantastic. I was worried that my question was too long-winded and would be too difficult to understand. This appears to work perfectly. Thanks for your help